# Display certain text based on user input

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have recently decided to make a FizzBuzz app to learn some iOS development. I have managed to create an app that allows the user to type in a number and it will display the number they have entered. I also have a for loop that runs through the numbers 1-100 and logs the number, fizz, buzz or fizz buzz. What I would like to do is have the label display one of the above options that my for loop does, fizz, buzz, fizz buzz or the number that the user entered.

Currently I have this code written for my button.

```
- (IBAction)sub:(id)sender {
    NSString *input = textf.text;
    lab.text=input;

    for (int i = 1; i <=100; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 15 == 0) NSLog(@"FizzBuzz");
        else if ( i % 3 == 0) NSLog(@"Fizz");
        else if ( i % 5 == 0) NSLog(@"Buzz");
        else NSLog(@"%d", i);
    }


}
```

I realise this won't work but haven't figured out how to do it. I have looked online and not found anything to help me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the user's input to an integer to use it for calculation. Then you simply set the label to the specific text:

```
- (IBAction)sub:(id)sender {
    NSInteger i = [self.textField.text integerValue];

    if (i % 15 == 0) {
        self.label.text = @"FizzBuzz";
    } else if ( i % 3 == 0) {
        self.label.text = @"Fizz";
    } else if ( i % 5 == 0) {
        self.label.text = @"Buzz";
    } else {
        self.label.text = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It's so simple when you see it typed out. Slightly off topic but do you have any websites or anything you recommend for learning?

Comment: I'd definitely recommend https://www.raywenderlich.com. You could also check out https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA.